# Relative consistency of ZF with respect to IZF

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, forcing, alternative-set-theories, heyting-algebra

Is there a forcing argument of this fact? Can anybody point me to the place?

The reason I'm asking is because I was reading Heyting-Valued Models for Intuitionistic Set Theory by R.J. Grayson, yet the proof of the theorem is largely the following quotation:

> $\text{For }x\subseteq 1,\text{ set }\bar{x}=\{y \in 1: y \notin x \}\text{ and let }\Omega=\{x\subseteq 1\;:\;x=\bar{\bar{x}}\}$
>
> $\text{ so }\Omega\text{ is a }\underline{\text{complete Boolean algebra}}\text{ in IZF.}$
>
> $\text{We denote this} \quad cBa \quad \text{by}\\P(1)/\neg\neg$
>
> $\text{since it is the quotient of }P(1) \text{ under the }\neg\neg\text{-operator}$.

So is the above simply a re-hash of the godelian "$\varphi$ is a theorem of $ZF$ if and only if $\neg\neg\varphi$ is a theorem in $IZF$" or is it something slightly more sophisticated? I am in particular looking for a forcing argument of this claim...

I was imagining something like the following:
Let $V$ be the universe of $IZF$, we construct a heyting valued model as follows. Let $\Omega_H := H$ where H is an arbitrary complete Heyting algebra. Define $V^{H}\in V$, i.e., $V^{H}=\bigcup V_{\alpha}^H$, in the normal way. We have $V^H \models IZF$. Let $\mathbb{P}=H$ be our forcing poset(Is this allowed?). Just as in the quote, for $x \subseteq 1$, set $\bar{x}=\{y \in 1: y \notin x \}$ and let $B=\{x \subseteq 1 : x = \bar{\bar{x}}\}$. Can we write $V^H/ \Omega_B=V^H[ \Omega_B]=V^B$, where $V^B$ is a Boolean valued model with $\Omega_B:=B$, or does this not make sense?

Edit: Also, I have read that forcing's relation to double negation is somehow related to "strong" versus "weak" forcing -- but I have a hard time finding definitions of these terms...

Comment: A closely related paper: Friedman, Harvey. “The Consistency of Classical Set Theory Relative to a Set Theory with Intuitionistic Logic.” The Journal of Symbolic Logic, vol. 38, no. 2, 1973, pp. 315–319. JSTOR, JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/2272068.

Comment: Yes, but this is a proof of godel's negative interpretation via the deductive systems of each logic. I was curious to see if this could be turned into a forcing argument about models and satisfiability rather than deductions -- I read somewhere that double negation was related to strong versus weak forcing... but I'll have to research more about this later -- perhaps my knowledge of this area is not deep enough.